# Run ShellScript Without Authorization Popup for MAC Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell, root, privileges

I am working on MAC Application in which I want to Remove Helper tool previously installed by my application.

I am using [STPrivilegedTask](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask) to run my ShellScript.
Here is the code I am using to achieve this.

```
NSString *pathForUninstallFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Uninstall" ofType:@"sh"];
STPrivilegedTask *taskToRemoveHelperTool = [STPrivilegedTask launchedPrivilegedTaskWithLaunchPath:pathForUninstallFile arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Uninstall.sh", nil]];
```

and here is my ShellScript Unistall.sh

```
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bsecure.HelperTool.plist
rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.appleCompany.HelperTool.plist
rm /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.appleCompany.HelperTool

security -q authorizationdb remove "com.appleCompany.readLicenseKey"
security -q authorizationdb remove "com.appleCompany.newMethod"
```

**Now the above code works perfect but it ask user's Authorization Popup.**

**I want to run this script without this Authorization Popup.**

**I already search in another question but none of them work for me that's why I created this question.**

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run a task with escalated privileges without prompting the user for a password?  If so, you're out of luck, it can't be done.